# What language is this javascript?

Tags: javascript

I dont know what this javascript real code ??

```
// Summary Config
var _0x7b08 = ["\x6B\x20\x33\x28\x68\x29\x7B\x33\x2E\x38\x3D\x33\x2E\x38\x7C\x7C\x30\x3B\x33\x2E\x38\x2B\x2B\x3B\x32\x20\x67\x3D\x37\x2E\x35\x2E\x6F\x28\x22\x2F\x6E\x2F\x75\x2F\x22\x29\x3D\x3D\x2D\x31\x26\x26\x37\x2E\x35\x2E\x6F\x28\x22\x2F\x6E\x3F\x22\x29\x3D\x3D\x2D\x31\x2C\x63\x3D\x37\x2E\x35\x2E\x6F\x28\x22\x2F\x6E\x2F\x75\x2F\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x3B\x36\x28\x33\x2E\x38\x3C\x3D\x34\x2E\x4D\x29\x7B\x39\x7D\x36\x28\x67\x26\x26\x21\x34\x2E\x59\x29\x7B\x39\x7D\x36\x28\x63\x26\x26\x21\x34\x2E\x31\x35\x29\x7B\x39\x7D\x32\x20\x65\x3D\x6D\x2E\x72\x28\x68\x29\x2C\x66\x3D\x65\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x22\x45\x22\x29\x3B\x36\x28\x34\x2E\x4B\x29\x7B\x32\x20\x61\x3D\x27\x3C\x4E\x20\x50\x3D\x22\x54\x22\x3E\x27\x3B\x32\x20\x64\x3D\x33\x2E\x6C\x28\x65\x2E\x6A\x2C\x34\x2E\x31\x32\x29\x7D\x31\x33\x7B\x32\x20\x61\x3D\x22\x22\x2C\x64\x3D\x33\x2E\x6C\x28\x65\x2E\x6A\x2C\x34\x2E\x31\x39\x29\x7D\x65\x2E\x6A\x3D\x61\x2B\x64\x2B\x22\x2E\x2E\x2E\x22\x7D\x33\x2E\x6C\x3D\x6B\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x29\x7B\x39\x20\x61\x2E\x31\x38\x28\x2F\x3C\x2E\x2A\x3F\x3E\x2F\x46\x2C\x22\x22\x29\x2E\x47\x28\x2F\x5C\x73\x2B\x2F\x29\x2E\x48\x28\x30\x2C\x62\x2D\x31\x29\x2E\x49\x28\x22\x20\x22\x29\x7D\x3B\x6B\x20\x4A\x28\x74\x29\x7B\x4C\x28\x32\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x31\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x32\x20\x70\x3D\x74\x2E\x4F\x2E\x70\x5B\x69\x5D\x3B\x32\x20\x76\x3D\x70\x2E\x51\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x52\x24\x53\x2E\x77\x3B\x6D\x2E\x55\x28\x27\x3C\x45\x20\x56\x3D\x22\x78\x22\x20\x58\x3D\x22\x78\x22\x20\x77\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x76\x2B\x27\x22\x2F\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x7D\x79\x2E\x5A\x3D\x6B\x28\x29\x7B\x32\x20\x65\x3D\x6D\x2E\x72\x28\x22\x31\x30\x22\x29\x3B\x36\x28\x65\x3D\x3D\x31\x31\x29\x7B\x79\x2E\x37\x2E\x35\x3D\x22\x7A\x3A\x2F\x2F\x41\x2E\x42\x2E\x43\x2F\x22\x7D\x65\x2E\x44\x28\x22\x35\x22\x2C\x22\x7A\x3A\x2F\x2F\x41\x2E\x42\x2E\x43\x2F\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x44\x28\x22\x31\x36\x22\x2C\x22\x20\x31\x37\x20\x71\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x6A\x3D\x22\x57\x20\x71\x22\x7D", "\x7C", "\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74", "\x7C\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x7C\x53\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x63\x6F\x75\x6E\x74\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x61\x7C\x6C\x61\x62\x65\x6C\x7C\x61\x76\x74\x72\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x32\x35\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x73\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x69\x67\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65\x7C\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x7C\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x73\x6B\x69\x70\x70\x65\x72\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x66\x65\x65\x64\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x7C\x67\x64\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x6F\x73\x7C\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x53\x6F\x72\x61\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x44\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x48\x6F\x6D\x65\x7C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x53\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x57\x6F\x72\x64\x73\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x44\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x4C\x61\x62\x65\x6C\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x42\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x73\x4E\x6F\x49\x6D\x67", "", "\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65", "\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65", "\x5C\x77\x2B", "\x5C\x62", "\x67"];
eval(function(_0x5ef0x1, _0x5ef0x2, _0x5ef0x3, _0x5ef0x4, _0x5ef0x5, _0x5ef0x6) {
    _0x5ef0x5 = function(_0x5ef0x3) {
        return (_0x5ef0x3 < _0x5ef0x2 ? _0x7b08[4] : _0x5ef0x5(parseInt(_0x5ef0x3 / _0x5ef0x2))) + ((_0x5ef0x3 = _0x5ef0x3 % _0x5ef0x2) > 35 ? String_0x7b08[5] : _0x5ef0x3.toString(36))
    };
    if (!_0x7b08[4] _0x7b08[6]) {
        while (_0x5ef0x3--) {
            _0x5ef0x6[_0x5ef0x5(_0x5ef0x3)] = _0x5ef0x4[_0x5ef0x3] || _0x5ef0x5(_0x5ef0x3)
        };
        _0x5ef0x4 = [function(_0x5ef0x5) {
            return _0x5ef0x6[_0x5ef0x5]
        }];
        _0x5ef0x5 = function() {
            return _0x7b08[7]
        };
        _0x5ef0x3 = 1;
    };
    while (_0x5ef0x3--) {
        if (_0x5ef0x4[_0x5ef0x3]) {
            _0x5ef0x1 = _0x5ef0x1[_0x7b08[6]](new RegExp(_0x7b08[8] + _0x5ef0x5(_0x5ef0x3) + _0x7b08[8], _0x7b08[9]), _0x5ef0x4[_0x5ef0x3])
        }
    };
    return _0x5ef0x1;
}(_0x7b08[0], 62, 72, _0x7b08[3] _0x7b08[2], 0, {}));
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be helpful for anybody in its current form.

Comment: Is it apparently for advertising "Sora Templates." Or, if certain contents are lacking from the page, it redirects the user away from your page to theirs. (I assume you're using a free website template.)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35562883/361762) on a different question has a handy snippet for de-obfuscating those unicode character strings. It won't fully tell you what the code does, but it's a good place to start if you want to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is coded hex code of this array of string.

```
|summary|Summary|href|if|location|count|return||||||||||innerHTML|function|strip|document|search|indexOf|entry|Templates|getElementById||data|label|avtr|src|25|window|http|www|soratemplates|com|setAttribute|img|ig|split|slice|join|authorshow|displayimages|for|skipper|div|feed|class|author|gd|image|contentos|write|width|Sora|height|DisplayHome|onload|mycontent|null|SummaryWords|else|getElementsByTagName|DisplayLabel|title|Blogger|replace|wordsNoImg"
```

This scripts are used by some designers to add footer credits in their templates. If you try to remove them you will redirect to the owner's website. However it is very easy to remove this footer credits by decoding the codes.